# How to turn off popular suggestions from Chrome Omnibar (not history/bookmarks)

Tags: google-chrome

I'm happy that Chrome shows me suggestions from my history and my bookmarks. I'm not happy that it shows me random "popular" completions.

[image]

How do I turn of those unwanted and completely unrelated to me suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, under "Sync and Google services" turn off "Autocomplete searches and URLs"

[image]

Now the irrelevant to me suggestions are gone

[image]